# How to iterate over nested objects using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I would like to know how to iterate over the following data object using handlebars.

Here is what it outputs:

```
image2.png | title2 
image3.png | title3
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
image1.png | title1
image2.png | title2 
image3.png | title3
```

Data

```
var data = {
  "item": [{ // item with one image
      "src" : "image1.png",
      "title" : "title1"
  }],
  "item": [{ // item with two or more images
      "src" : "image2.png",
      "title" : "title2"
  },
  {
      "src" : "image3.png",
      "title" : "title3"
  }]
}

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#data-template").text());
var html = template(data);
$('#placeholder').html(html);
```

Template

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="data-template">
    {{#item}}
       {{src}} | {{title}} <br>
    {{/item}}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88CwB/

Comment: That is not valid JSON. It looks like you are overwriting data. First creating an "item" property with a single element array, then overwriting the "item" property with a 2 element array.

Comment: I suspect you will need to turn your broken JSON object into an array of valid JSON objects, each with an `item` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.

Handlebars can only see 2 items.

```
var data = {
  "item": [{ // item with one image
      "src" : "image1.png",
      "title" : "title1"
  }],
  "item": [{ // item with two or more images
      "src" : "image2.png",
      "title" : "title2"
  },
  {
      "src" : "image3.png",
      "title" : "title3"
  }]
}


var template = Handlebars.compile($("#data-template").text());
var html = template(data);
$('#placeholder').html("<p>" + data.item + "</p>");
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hZQnD/1/

You can fix it by making your `data` object contain only 1 `item` object, which may contain an array of 3 items.

```
var data = {
  "item": [{ // item with 3 images
      "src" : "image1.png",
      "title" : "title1"
  },
  {
      "src" : "image2.png",
      "title" : "title2"
  },
  {
      "src" : "image3.png",
      "title" : "title3"
  }]
}


var template = Handlebars.compile($("#data-template").text());
var html = template(data);
$('#placeholder').html(html);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/75UzZ/1/

You can also fix it by making your data object an array of objects with `item` properties and iterating through them in a for loop:

```
var data = [{
    "item": [{ // item with one image
        "src" : "image1.png",
        "title" : "title1"
    }]
  },{
    "item": [{ // item with two or more images
        "src" : "image2.png",
        "title" : "title2"
    },
    {
        "src" : "image3.png",
        "title" : "title3"
    }]
}];

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#data-template").text());
var html = ""
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i ){
  html += template(data[i]);
}
$('#placeholder').html(html);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dFmQG/2/